# Why does my Android Calculator crash?

Tags: java, android

Why is my app crashing? I'm using eclipse. I don't see why it would crash. Everything seems fine to me. No missing semi-colins that I see.

```
package rechee.cool;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;




public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public EditText display;

    double total1=0;
    double total2=0;
    char theOperator;       

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);    
        display= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    }

    String display1= display.getText().toString();


    public void getOperator(String btnText){
        theOperator = btnText.charAt(0);
        double displayValue= Double.parseDouble(display1);
        total1+=displayValue;
        display.setText("");
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.bOne:
            display.append("1");
            break;
        case R.id.bTwo:
            display.append("2");
            break;
        case R.id.bThree:
            display.append("3");
            break;
        case R.id.bFour:
            display.append("4");
            break;
        case R.id.bFive:
            display.append("5");
            break;
        case R.id.bSix:
            display.append("6");
            break;
        case R.id.bSeven:
            display.append("7");
            break;
        case R.id.bEight:
            display.append("8");
            break;
        case R.id.bNine:
            display.append("9");
            break;
        case R.id.bZero:
            display.append("0");
            break;
        case R.id.bPoint:
            display.append(".");
            break;
        case R.id.bClear:
            display.setText("");
            break;
        case R.id.bAdd:
            String btn_text= (String) getText(R.id.bAdd);
            display.setText(btn_text);
            //getOperator(display1);
            break;
            //case R.id.bEqual:
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace from the crash. Otherwise we have no idea where to start looking.

Comment: And in proper formatting. Yours is **extremely** horrible.

Comment: Theoretical +1 for "semi-colins". I know some guys who are full Colins .

Answer (score 0):

Dude, you have to post stackface.  My face when no stacktrace --> :|

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    display= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);} // <--This curly brace is probably the problem
    String display1= display.getText().toString();




    public void getOperator(String btnText){
        theOperator = btnText.charAt(0);
        double displayValue= Double.parseDouble(display1);
        total1+=displayValue;
        display.setText("");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're getting a NullPointerException.

```
String display1= display.getText().toString();
```

That line is actually declaring an instance member of your `HelloAndroidActivity` class, which, when initialization is attempted, is referring to `display`, which is null.

Answer (score 0):

I think that onCreatemethod you should add after:

```
display= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

this:

```
display.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and also you should add final like this:

```
final public EditText display;

final double total1=0;
final double total2=0;
final char theOperator;  
final String display1= display.getText().toString();
```

Try to put in comments your getOperator method and see if this works. Oh and as GriffeyDog said you have a big error there. Get the text once the screen has been painted, eg. after:

`display= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);`

Answer (score 0):

do this.

```
...

 String display1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);    
        display= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        display1= display.getText().toString()
    }


...
```